# How to handle asynchronous axios api call

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to add a property to the all allIco's object from the tgram array / axios api call. When I add the property using .map its value is undefined. I know it's because my api call is asynchronous but I can't figure out how to add an axios.all...any help would be appreciated :)

```
  var allIcos = Object.assign(ico.results);
  let tgram = [];
  var result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < allIcos.length; i++) {
    axios.get(`url=@${tgramUrl[allIcos[i].name]}`).then(response => {
        tgram.push(response.data.result);
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  var result = allIcos.map((obj,i) => Object.assign({telegram:"test"}, obj));
  this.setState({data: allIcos});
  console.log(allIcos);
```

Comment: you're making multiple AJAX calls inside for-loop and they're async in nature. can't you make a single call and get all elements together?

Answer (score 1):

what about try `promise.all`?

```
const promises = [];

for (let i = 0; i < allIcos.length; i++) {
    promises.push(axios.get(`url=@${tgramUrl[allIcos[i].name]}`));
}

Promise.all(promises).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
});
```

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see is to perform map and setState every time there is a response from the axios call (inside the 'then' clause. Unless you can make one axios call for all (and then, the setState and map should also be inside the 'then', but you know that).